# Why I am getting AttributeError: __getitem__

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert a string to a list of characters.After that I will compare that list to another string and I want to remove common elements.But I am getting AttributeError: **getitem**

Please have a look.

Here is my code:

```
  def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):

        result = []
        for word in string.ascii_lowercase:
            result.append[word]

        for guessedItem in lettersGuessed:
            result.remove(guessedItem)
        return result

   print getAvailableLetters(['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "D:\devs\source\PythonTest\test1.py", line 118, in ?
  File "D:\devs\source\PythonTest\test1.py", line 112, in getAvailableLetters
AttributeError: __getitem__
```

Any help is appreciated.

BTW line 112 is

```
result.append[word]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result.append[word]
```

This is your problem. You used square brackets instead of parens. The interpreter thinks you are trying to access the value with the key `word` in the `append` object.